# Composer Laravel Class 'yajra\Datatables\DatatablesServiceProvider' not found

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces, composer-php

I have a problem with `laravel` and `composer package` [yajra/laravel-datatables](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables)
Here is my require part from `composer.json`:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
    "cartalyst/sentinel": "^2.0",
    "laravelcollective/html": "^5.2",
    "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "^6.1"
},
```

After executing `composer update` all passes fine and I can check that inside vendor dir has appeared yajra folder.
After that I have add new provider in app.php:

```
yajra\Datatables\DatatablesServiceProvider::class
```

and then run php artisan but followingerror appears in the console:

```
Class 'yajra\Datatables\DatatablesServiceProvider' not found
```

I can fix this error by editing `autoload_classmap.php` file and manually add

```
'yajra\\Datatables\\DatatablesServiceProvider' => $vendorDir . '/yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle/src/DatatablesServiceProvider.php',
```

Anyway, the next time I execute composer update this line is deleted and again appears the same error and I again have to manually edit `autoload_classmap.php` file.

There is something wrong which causes `composer update` to not update relevant autoload files. I can not get it what is going on.

Comment: Have you tried running `composer dump-autoload`?

Answer (score 4):

You should use in your `app.php`

```
Yajra\Datatables\DatatablesServiceProvider::class
```

instead of

```
yajra\Datatables\DatatablesServiceProvider::class
```

(with capital letter)

Comment: It wasn't issue with capital letter.  Recreating composer with 

"require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",

        "laravelcollective/html": "5.2.*",
        "cartalyst/sentinel": "2.0.*",
        "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "~5.0"

    },

somehow solves problem.

Comment: This fixed the problem for me when I was upgrading from 5.x to 6.x

Comment: I can not reproduce it any more.

Answer (score 2):

Try removing syntactic sugar operators like tilde and caret sign in composer.json. Because sometimes they do not allow the exact version to install. The same problem happened to me also. Then run,

```
comoposer update
```

Solved the issue for me.