# Class DataTable not found in laravel

Tags: laravel

I try to install Laravel DataTable and after I run command

php artisan vendor:publish
and then it get error and I use laravel 5.4

```
    [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
      Class 'Yajra\Datatables\DatatablesServiceProvider' not found
```

Comment: check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34696817/composer-laravel-class-yajra-datatables-datatablesserviceprovider-not-found) and the [upgrade guide](https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/7.0/upgrade)

Comment: which version of data table are you using??

Comment: Have you added the Provider in your config/app.php file ?

Comment: I use version 7.0 and I already add config/app.php file.

Comment: May try clearning cache and check by doing "php artisan config:cache"